# Configuration for Cassandra on single node

Tags: cassandra, key, partitioning, apache-spark

We have single Cassandra node.

With table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  pk bigint,
  b text,
  d int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((pk))
);

CREATE INDEX test_d_idx ON test (d);
```

The query in *cqlsh*

```
select * from test where d = 20140407
```

work fast, as well.

But DataStax driver for Spark generates query:

```
SELECT "d", "b" FROM "test" WHERE token("pk") > 6755909504673608635 AND d = 20140407 ALLOW FILTERING
```

which is slow.

```
SELECT partitioner FROM system.local;
```

returns

```
> org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
```

Question: how to configure one node in such way, that SELECT with token("pk") would work fast?

Table contains 10^7 rows (if table contains 1000 rows, it works fast, obviously).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT "d", "b" FROM "test" 
WHERE token("pk") > 6755909504673608635 AND d = 20140407 ALLOW FILTERING
```

Wow, Spark generated that query?  The reason this doesn't work (well) is that queries on secondary indexes in the `WHERE` clause only work in conjunction with the `PRIMARY KEY` when the `PRIMARY KEY` value is specified with an equals operator.  Basically the <kbd>></kbd> operator is not giving Cassandra enough information to know on which partition the value is on, so it has to search them all (which is why it takes so long).

I feel the better option here, is instead of a secondary index on `test(d)`, create an additional query table (and modify your application to persist data out to that table as well):

```
CREATE TABLE testbyd (
  d int,
  pk bigint,
  b text,
  PRIMARY KEY (d,pk)
);
```

While I can't say how Spark will treat that table, I can tell you that this CQL query will work on that table:

```
SELECT d, b
FROM testbyd
WHERE d=20140407 AND pk > 6755909504673608635;
```

Likewise, this CQL query:

```
select * from testbyd where d = 20140407;
```

...will perform much better than it will against the "test" table.  In any case, give that a shot and see how Spark treats that query table.